# Need help installing ELCImagePickerController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

I was excited when I ran across [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController). When following the instructions on their website and github, it crashes when I try to show it. I coppied the `ELC Image Picker` folder inside my app, and I have changed the following in my .h:

```
#import "ELCImagePickerController.h" 
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <OHGridViewDelegate, OHGridViewDataSource, UIActionSheetDelegate, ELCImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate> {
```

And in my .m

```
#import "ELCImagePickerController.h"
#import "ELCAlbumPickerController.h"

ELCImagePickerController *controller = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initImagePicker];
        [controller setDelegate:self];
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        [controller release];
```

When trying to build, it gives me the warning `No '-initImagePicker' method found`. Am I missing something simple here?

Please help!
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the latest commit from github? There has been an update. This page shows how to call it now: http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/03/03/update-elcimagepickercontroller/.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the `initImagePicker` method is present in `ELCImagePickerController.h`.

Also, I guess the Readme in Github is not updated.

Try using the `-(void)selectedAssets:(NSArray*)_assets` method implemented in `ELCImagePickerController.m`.